# How to create a new variable using mutate to compute p-value from other 4 columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I`m trying to compute the p-value for several data that came from 4 columns, containing the number of observations and the desired cases for two distinct groups.

When I use mutate like the example bellow:

```
  data %>%
      mutate(pvalue = prop.test(c(p1, p2), c(n1, n2), conf.level = 0.9)$p.value)
```

But when I look to the results, all of them are 0's, and I`m sure that some of them are different than that.

I suppose that the prop.test function is calculating the values for the sum of each column instead of case by case.

Can someone help please?

PS: This is my first question on Stack Overflow, any tips are welcome as well.

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data. Your guess about `prop.test` sounds reasonable, but someone can help you out with that for sure once we can see the data

Comment: Possibly `data %>% rowwise() %>%
      mutate(pvalue = prop.test(c(p1, p2), c(n1, n2), conf.level = 0.9)$p.value)`? This makes dplyr evaluate each row separately.

Comment: @Mako212  I don't know why but following your recommendation for a sample data, it worked perfectly:  'data <- data.frame(p1 = rbinom(10, 500, 0.7), p2 = c(rbinom(10, 500, 0.6)), n1 = as.integer(rep(500, 10)), n2 = as.integer(rep(500,10)))

data %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pvalue = prop.test(c(p1,p2),c(n1,n2), conf.level = 0.9)$p.value)'  But for my data it didn't with the following error:  Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: not enough data.  Could it be related to NAs?

Comment: The first thing I would check is if `apply(data, 2, length)` shows the same number of entries for `p1`, `p2`, `n1`, `n2`. Assuming length is equal, try filtering out `NA` values.